# How can I fill in the background behind text when I hover over it in a nav bar? [HTML/CSS]

Tags: html, css

I have a nav bar right now that works exactly as intended, except for one minor thing: When I hover over it, the opacity change does not reach all the way down to the bottom. 
Here are a couple screenshots:
This: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7Ilv.jpg shows what it looks like unselected
This: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6X2F8.jpg shows what it looks like when my cursor is on top

As you can see, the slight blank space on the bottom hurt to look at, and I don't know how to remedy it. My HTML/CSS is as follows:

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar center affix" role="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href=# itemprop="url"><span itemprop="titlenav">Home</span></a></li></ul></div>
```

CSS:

```
 .navbar {
    background-color:#747A80;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px #5E5E5E;
    top:0px;
    border-bottom:solid #000000;
}

.navbar li {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar li a{
    display: block;
    padding:15px;
    margin-bottom:-10px;
    line-height:20px;
    color:#F9F9F9;
}

.navbar li:hover {
    opacity:1;
    background:#575A5C
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WE5v3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WE5v3/1/)

To remove the margin that browsers add by default, add this code:

```
.navbar > ul {
    margin: 0;
}
```

And remove this:

```
.navbar li a{
    margin-bottom:-10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove ul margin

```
.navbar ul{
    margin:0px;
}
```

and  remove `a` margin

http://jsfiddle.net/Gv9Gj/